# AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command' "line 6 in module @client.command()

Tags: python, discord.py, client

My code keeps showing "AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'" Does anyone know how to fix this? code is below import discord
import os.

````
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.command()
async def hornyjail(ctx, member: discord.Member, time: int, d, *, reason=None):
    guild = ctx.guild

    for role in guild.roles:
        if role.name == "Horny Jailed":
            await member.add_roles(role)

            embed = discord.Embed(title="jailed!", description=f"{member.mention} has been horny jailed ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
            embed.add_field(name="reason:", value=reason, inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name="time left for the jail:", value=f"{time}{d}", inline=False)
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

            if d == "s":
                await asyncio.sleep(time)

            if d == "m":
                await asyncio.sleep(time*60)

            if d == "h":
                await asyncio.sleep(time*60*60)

            if d == "d":
                await asyncio.sleep(time*60*60*24)

            await member.remove_roles(role)

            embed = discord.Embed(title="The Beautiful Sky! (temp) ", description=f"Freed -{member.mention} ", colour=discord.Colour.light_gray())
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

            return

client.run(os.env('TOKEN'))```
````

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have commands with `discord.Client`, for commands support you should use `commands.Bot`

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
```

Answer (score -1):

see bro at your import statements import discord, import os | its saying client has no attribute command because u need - from discord.ext import commands below import os to import commamds else it will say client has no attribute command

welcome!